Window Function with multiple conditions to DELETE records from Table
This is my table:

I need to delete those records where there is NL46 ShopCode, but only if the ProductCode has ShopCode 'FR43','FR44' or 'FR45'.
I only need to keep the rows with NL46 if these ShopCodes don't belong to the ProductCode.
I used WindowFunction:
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ShopCode = 'NL46' AND SUM(CASE WHEN SHOPCODE = 'NL46' THEN 0 ELSE 1) OVER  PARTITION BY ProductCode > 0

But it does not work.
The confusing thing is that there are other ShopCodes which I don't know how to handle.

which database system are ypu using and please don't mages of data and code see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

does not work how? Error or not the result you expect?

I'd simply use EXISTS to make sure at least one of 'FR43', 'FR44' and 'FR45' also exists.
DELETE FROM MyTable m1
WHERE ShopCode = 'NL46'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable m2
              WHERE m2.ProductCode = m1.ProductCode 
                AND m2.ShopCode IN ('FR43', 'FR44', 'FR45'))


We can use two IN clauses, one checking the product code and one checking the shop code:
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE 
  ShopCode = 'NL46'
  AND ProductCode IN
    (SELECT ProductCode FROM MyTable WHERE ShopCode IN ('FR43', 'FR44', 'FR45'));

See this demo with your sample data.

This does not consider the different ProductCode, i only need to delete the NL rows if the same productCode has ShopCode FR43,FR44 or FR45 :(

The delete command in this answer and also the one in this answer produce exactly the result you described in your question and delete exactly those rows you want to delete. See the fiddle I linked in my answer, it proves that. If this is not what you want, your question is asked incorrectly. In this case please create a new one and fix it. By the way, if it would not consider the ProductCode, the row PQ333, NL46 would also be deleted. But as you see in the fiddle, it is not.
